# Error messages when attempting to plot a complicated function in R

Tags: r

I have written some code to demonstrate the benefits of diversifying across a range of assets when planning a portfolio.

```
#Portfolio variance
y <- function(x) {
  vars <- rnorm(n = x, mean = 0.7, sd = 0.07)
    # rho generating function:
    ranrho <- function(z) {
    c(rep(0, times = z), runif(n = x-z, min = -1, max = 0.9)) + 0.1
    }
    #you get the lower diagonal of the covar matrix:
    rhold <- sapply(1:x, ranrho)
    rhold
    #and the full corr matrix
  corr <- rhold + t(rhold)
  corr <- corr * sqrt(vars)
  corr <- t(t(corr) * sqrt(vars))
  #And the variance-covariance matrix:
    vcov <- corr + if(x==1) {vars
    } else {diag(vars)}
  #And recover the portfolio variance through the following equation
    portvar <- (1/x^2)*sum(vars) + if(x==1) { as.numeric(0)
  } else {(1/x^2)*(sum(corr)/2)}
  return(portvar)
}

y(1)
y(5)
y(10)
y(20)
y(50)
y(100)

plot(1:100, y(1:100))
```

y returns a single value for each value of x that is inputted. x is an integer representing number of assets and y is the consequent variance of the portfolio. I have examples for different values of x and each return a sensible value for y with no issues.

My problem is that I'm getting the following error when trying to plot my function:

Error in rhold + t(rhold) : non-conformable arrays
In addition: Warning message:
In 1:x : numerical expression has 100 elements: only the first used

Firstly, since the code works when I write y([whatever]), rhold and t(rhold) are clearly conformable. I'm not sure what the second error means. Am I using the plot function wrong?

Another issue - I have looked but can't seem to find how you might plot a function which only accepts integer values of x in its domain, but returns values of y on the continuous real line.

Grateful for any help.

Comment: Downvote for failing to read the error message and for posting a misleading question title. The problem is in the design of your algorithm. In R teh if function takes a single value. There must be 100 or more questions on SO that have this error message, so failure to search is yet another reason to downvote.

Comment: I did read the error message but I didn't understand it. I searched the error message and didn't see anything which related to this particular. I only started learning R a week ago so that might be why I don't get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that your function expects a single numeric and you are using 100

Just use lappy:

```
#Portfolio variance
y <- function(x) {
  vars <- rnorm(n = x, mean = 0.7, sd = 0.07)
  # rho generating function:
  ranrho <- function(z) {
    c(rep(0, times = z), runif(n = x-z, min = -1, max = 0.9)) + 0.1
  }
  #you get the lower diagonal of the covar matrix:
  rhold <- sapply(1:x, ranrho)
  rhold
  #and the full corr matrix
  corr <- rhold + t(rhold)
  corr <- corr * sqrt(vars)
  corr <- t(t(corr) * sqrt(vars))
  #And the variance-covariance matrix:
  vcov <- corr + if(x==1) {vars
  } else {diag(vars)}
  #And recover the portfolio variance through the following equation
  portvar <- (1/x^2)*sum(vars) + if(x==1) { as.numeric(0)
  } else {(1/x^2)*(sum(corr)/2)}
  return(portvar)
}

y(1)
y(5)
y(10)
y(20)
y(50)
y(100)

plot(1:100,lapply(1:100,y))
```

Comment: That's it! Thanks so much